# Update unique or primary keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, primary-key

I'm building a database management tool for a client to use on his own, and I'm having some problem dealing with the possibility of the update of primary/unique keys. So, given that the data for the update is passed by a PHP script on a per row basis, here's what I've come up with (from "immediatly" to "after some time"):

1. DELETE/INSERT instead of UPDATE (awful, I now...):

   ```
   DELETE FROM table WHERE unique_key=x;
   DELETE FROM table WHERE unique_key=y;
   INSERT INTO table VALUES (unique_key=y, field=record1), (unique_key=x, field=record2);
   ```
2. Alter my primary/unique key and then substitute them with the modified value:

   ```
   UPDATE table SET unique_key=x* WHERE unique_key=x;
   UPDATE table SET unique_key=y* WHERE unique_key=y;
   UPDATE table SET unique_key=y WHERE unique_key=x*;
   UPDATE table SET unique_key=x WHERE unique_key=y*;
   ```
3. Add a not modifiable auto_increment field "id" to all my tables, which act as a surrogate primary key

As now, I'm on the route of adding an "id" field to everything. Other options?

Comment: I am not really understanding what your use case is here. Why would you need to update primary keys like that on a regular basis?  I am guessing that perhaps your problem is more with schema design, then the mechanics of how you are going to update these rows.  You mention option number three (which is EXTREMELY common practice in relational databases) as if it is an afterthought.  Why don't your tables have immutable primary keys to begin with?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Surely the database could have been designed better, I'm getting started. As for the frequency of the key update, if any it will be done every now and then, the fact is that it could, and I've been asked for something that allow them to modify as much as possible (it should be a mini-phpmyAdmin, to say so).

Comment: In practice there is no such thing as an "immutable" key. Surrogate key values sometimes change too. *Stability* is a useful and desirable property when choosing and designing keys; *immutability* is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a primary key isn't a problem; all values in SQL (and in the relational model) are supposed to be updatable.

The problem seems to be *swapping* primary keys, which

- doesn't make sense to me if you use surrogate keys (because they're meaningless, so updates aren't necessary) and which
- doesn't make sense to me if you use natural keys, because that's like swapping *my* StackOverflow userid with yours.

Adding an "ID" column to every table won't help you. The "unique_key" column *still* has to be declared unique.  Adding an "ID" column doesn't change that business requirement.

You *could* swap primary key values if MySQL supported deferred constraints. (Deferred constraints are a feature in standard SQL.)  But MySQL doesn't support that feature. In PostgreSQL, for example, you could do this.

```
create table test (
  unique_key char(1) primary key deferrable initially immediate,
  other_column varchar(15) not null
);

insert into test values 
('x', 'record2'),
('y', 'record1');

begin;
set constraints test_pkey deferred;
update test set unique_key = 'y' where other_column = 'record2';
update test set unique_key = 'x' where other_column = 'record1';
commit;

select * from test;

unique_key  other_column
--
y           record2
x           record1
```

Comment: You got it, swapping unique values it's exactly the point, and adding a surrogate keys doesn't solve that. Maybe I see why you say it wouldn't make sense anyway... I may instead update all the other (non-unique) fields instead, isn't it? `UPDATE table SET field='record2' WHERE unique_key=x;` I'd just have to let PHP find swap cases and manage them with an appropriate query.

Comment: In the general case, you can't swap details by updating everything *but* the primary key because, in the general case, that might involve swapping other candidate keys. (It's the same problem you run into by adding a surrogate key; deferrable constraints work in both cases.) I'm trying to imagine a case where this kind of "identity swapping" makes sense, but I'm failing. What do you imagine?

Comment: So, I've finally managed to set up a PHP script that check for duplicates and swaps among the incoming modified values, compares with the a temporary copy of the original data, and builds query accordingly. After all, it's not worth it, you're right. What I did imagine is basically a mistake I made, building at least two table with a concatenate field as a primary key instead of setting up a multiple primary key, plus trying to make it work whaterver they would like to modify in future, but in the end primary keys should indeed be not modifiable. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: *"primary keys should indeed be not modifiable"* I'd disagree with *that*; I've been through several mergers where surrogate PKs had to be changed in order to merge data. I just can't yet imagine a case where *swapping* them makes sense in the real world. Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a CASE expression to do this kind of update. For example:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col =
    CASE    WHEN col = 1 THEN 2
            WHEN col = 2 THEN 1
    END
WHERE col IN (1,2);
```

(untested code)

Comment: The above code did not work for me.